# How can I create a blank fragment without including factory methods in Android Studio 4.0 +?

Tags: android, android-studio

I had created a fragment without the factory methods in android studio 3.6 however I cannot find the option in android studio 4.0. Could someone tell me how I can do the same. Thanks!

Comment: The option to deselect factory method creation seems to have been removed after the update. I hope they add it back in the next update

Comment: I had exactly the same doubt. I don't know why they removed that feature in last update